# Customize splash screen on live CD. || Initrd.lz problem

Tags: boot, lubuntu, live-cd, plymouth

I try to customize splash screen on live CD session LUBUNTU 14.04.

According to [this solution](http://askubuntu.com.80bola.com/questions/10258/how-to-change-live-cd-splash-screen), i need to edit initrd.lz file and replace with my own plymouth theme.

So..

```
# cd extract-cd/casper
# mkdir lztempdir
# cd lztempdir
# lzma -dc -S .lz ../initrd.lz | cpio -imvd --no-absolute-filenames
# cp ../initrd.lz ../inird.lz.orig
# find . | cpio --quiet --dereference -o -H newc | lzma -7 > ../initrd.lz
```

After that i create usb with my custom iso. But when i connect usb to my device and start booting i got something like this:

/sbin/udevadm: line 1: ELF: not found
/sbin/udevadm: line 3: syntax error: unexpected "("
/sbin/udevadm: line 1: ELF: not found
/sbin/udevadm: line 3: syntax error: unexpected "("
/sbin/udevadm: line 1: ELF: not found
/sbin/udevadm: line 3: syntax error: unexpected "("

Interesing fact is that, even when i leave initrd.lz execalty as it is -> uncompress and pack again, these error above shows too...

Comment: Your last sentence suggests that potentially the issue is not with the splash screen, but some other part of the image. You might try remaking your image with no modifications to the splash and test the live CD to verify that your image is working correctly without the new splash.

Comment: dosen't work either.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This I have got 100% solution and done 99% of customization from here!!**

Install pre-requisities
Make sure that you have installed the needed tools

```
sudo apt-get install squashfs-tools genisoimage
```

Obtain the base system
Download an official Desktop CD from http://releases.ubuntu.com/

Note: the example shown here uses the ubuntu-9.04-desktop-i386.iso Desktop CD. Replace it with the name of your iso. For example, if you have a ubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.iso image, the command:

```
mv ubuntu-9.04-desktop-i386.iso ~/livecdtmp
```

would be changed to:

```
mv ubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.iso ~/livecdtmp
```

Move or copy it into an empty directory

```
mkdir ~/livecdtmp
mv ubuntu-9.04-desktop-i386.iso ~/livecdtmp
cd ~/livecdtmp
```

Extract the CD .iso contents
Mount the Desktop .iso

```
mkdir mnt
sudo mount -o loop ubuntu-9.04-desktop-i386.iso mnt
```

Extract .iso contents into dir 'extract-cd'

```
mkdir extract-cd
sudo rsync --exclude=/casper/filesystem.squashfs -a mnt/ extract-cd
```

Extract the Desktop system
Extract the SquashFS filesystem

```
sudo unsquashfs mnt/casper/filesystem.squashfs
sudo mv squashfs-root edit
```

Prepare and chroot
WARNING: If you do this in 14.04 LTS, you will lose network connectivity (name resolving part of it). /etc/resolv.conf is and should remain a symlink to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf nowadays. To enable name resolving, temporarily edit that file instead. If you need the network connection within chroot

```
sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf edit/etc/
```

NOTE: Recommended that you do not do this unless you know what you're doing Depending on your configuration, you may also need to copy the hosts file

```
sudo cp /etc/hosts edit/etc/
```

The remaining steps are good, unlike the ones above:

```
sudo mount --bind /dev/ edit/dev
sudo chroot edit
mount -t proc none /proc
mount -t sysfs none /sys
mount -t devpts none /dev/pts
```

(these mount important directories of your host system - if you later decide to delete the edit/ directory, then make sure to unmount before doing so, otherwise your host system will become unusable at least temporarily until reboot)

To avoid locale issues and in order to import GPG keys

```
export HOME=/root
export LC_ALL=C
```

Customizations
Apt-get
Prerequisites

In 9.10, before installing or upgrading packages you need to run

```
dbus-uuidgen > /var/lib/dbus/machine-id
```

and

```
dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl
ln -s /bin/true /sbin/initctl
```

**From here Now you can do all your customization in depth!!**

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall plymouth-theme*
```

or any other theme u want to install and save it with

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: Ok.. but any changes that i make are in filesystem.squashfs. Splash boot screen starting before this, splash is in initrd.lz